# How do I use a DataFrame to conditionally create documents using Jinja?

Tags: python, pandas, jinja2

For each row in a DataFrame I would like to print out some values for an avro schema. I have a DataFrame that looks something like this.

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame({'column' : ['id','type','time']
    , 'desc': ['the sk',' the type' , 'epoch time']
    ,'nullable':[False, False, True]})

print x
```

For each row in the DataFrame I would like to create inputs for a Jinja template

So my output would look something like:

```
{
name       : "id"
description: "the sk"
}
{
name       :"type"
description:"the type"
}
{
name       :"time","null"
description:"epoch time"
}
```

How can I do that? I would also like to nest results conditionally based on other column values from my dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I think transforming the `DataFrame` to a `dict` is the solution. I use `orient='records'` to get a `dict` suitable for rendering.

```
from jinja2 import Template

# Template definition
template = Template("""{% for row in data %}
{
name:  {{ row['column'] }}{{ ', null' if row['nullable'] }}
description: {{ row['desc'] }}
}
{% endfor %}""")

# Rendering
print(template.render(name='John Doe', data=x.to_dict(orient='records')))

# {
# name:  id
# description: the sk
# }
# 
# {
# name:  type
# description:  the type
# }
#
# {
# name:  time, null
# description: epoch time
# }
```

Comment: I had done that, but where I run into an issue is conditionally adding values to the template. for example add null if df[nullable] is true.

Comment: In this case you have to implement it in Jinja like this `{{ 'null' if row['nullable'] }}`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: TY for you help

Comment: Would you possibly be able to help me figure out how to nest these results under parent values? lets say I wanted to wrap the current output under a new parent column that could have some columns with either 1-1 parent = child or 1 to many parent to child1,....child n

Comment: I think jinja may not be what you are looking for. Have you tried converting the ´DataFrame´ to json?

Comment: I was actually trying to turn my data frame into a bunch of files. I used it to create a DB schema, view, and config, and lastly I am trying to make is spit out an Avro file.